# Aframe .setAttribute() of an entity that has multiples of that component

Tags: javascript, aframe

given an entity

```
<a-entity animation__foo="" animation__bar""> </a-entity>
```

I would like to

```
entity.setAttribute("animation__foo", "enabled: false;");
entity.setAttribute("animation__bar", "enabled: false;");
```

what is the proper syntax to do this? and is it possible to set the attributes at the same time in a single command?

Comment: Isn't that just working?

Comment: This should work. I recommend checking the [A-Frame docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#adding-a-component-with-setattribute). Let us know if you're missing any info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.8.0/src/core/a-entity.js):

> setAttribute can: 
>      1. Set a single property of a multi-property component. 
>      2. Set multiple properties of a multi-property component. 
>      3. Replace properties of a multi-property component. 
>      4. Set a value for a single-property component, mixin, or normal HTML attribute.

So, for a single property change, just do

```
entity.setAttribute("animation__foo", "enabled", "false;");
```

for multiple properties, try

```
entity.setAttribute("foo", {
    "one": "foo",
    "two": "bar"})
```

Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ectx2k57/).

---

If you want to update multiple components with one `setAttribute()`, it's not possible.